# Integrate $\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin^3t}{\sin^3t+\cos^3t}dt$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How to integrate

$$
\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin^3t}{\sin^3t+\cos^3t}dt\,?
$$

I tried to use $\sin^3tdt=-(1-\cos^2t)d\cos t$. But the term $\sin^3t$ in the denominator can not be simplified. Can anyone give me a hand? Thanks.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439851/evaluate-the-integral-int-frac-pi2-0-frac-sin3x-sin3x-cos3xdx

Comment: Also http://math.stackexchange.com/q/198083/17976

Answer (score 6, accepted):

General Hint:

By setting $x=\pi/2-y$ you can see that $$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin^m(x)}{\sin^m(x)+\cos^m(x)}dx=\pi/4,~~m\in\mathbb R$$

Comment: Nice general hint! +1